# Generic inheritance and overloaded operator +

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class "ArrayTemp" that creates an array of pointers to type T and am trying to create a derived template that will perform numeric operations. I am having trouble implementing a operator + that will add the elements of each array and return a new array with the sums.

My template base class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ArrayTemp
{
private:
    T* arr;
    int arrSize;
    static int DSize;

public:
    ArrayTemp(): arrSize(DSize), arr(new T[DSize]) {}
    ArrayTemp(const ArrayTemp<T>& at): arrSize(at.arrSize), arr(new T[at.arrSize]) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < at.arrSize; ++i)
            arr[i] = at.arr[i];
    }
    ~ArrayTemp()
    {
        delete [] arr;
    }

    ArrayTemp<T>& operator = (const ArrayTemp<T>& source)
{
    if (this != &source)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
            setElement(source.getElement(i), i);
    }
            return *this;
}

    int getarrSize() { return arrSize; }
    T& getElement(const int index) { return arr[index]; }
    void setElement(const T& x, int index) { arr[index] = x; }
};
```

My derived template:

```
#pragma once

#include "ArrayTemp.h"

template <class T>
class numbers: public ArrayTemp<T>
{
public:
    numbers(): ArrayTemp<T>()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (getarrSize()); ++i)
            setElement(0, i);
    }
    numbers(const numbers<T>& n): ArrayTemp<T>(const ArrayTemp<T>& x) {}
    ~numbers(){}

    numbers<T> operator + (const numbers<T>& n) const 
    {
        numbers<int> arraysum;

        for (int i = 0; i < getarrSize(); ++i)
            arraysum.setElement((n.getElement(i) + getElement(i)), i);

        return arraysum;
    }
};

template <class T> int ArrayTemp<T>::DSize = 5;
```

So I can do something like this in main():

```
numbers<int> n1;
numbers<int> n2;
numbers<int> n3;

n3 = n1 + n2;
```

How is an overloaded operator + supposed to be implemented within a structure similar to the one I have presented above? Should I try something with a copy constructor returning the numbers object? Also, I presume since there are no new data members in the derived template, that defining an assignment operator that just calls the ArrayTemp assignment operator is sufficient?

Errors I am getting trying this method:

```
cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const numbers<T>' to 'ArrayTemp<T> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
while compiling class template member function 'numbers<T> numbers<T>::operator +(const numbers<T> &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're experiencing? If there's an error in your addition operator, it may be due to you declaring the return type as numbers<int> instead of numbers<T>.

Comment: This kind of implies that the + operator is defined for every type T. When you add the two elements (n.getElement(i) + getElement(i)), you're using the + operator on two elements of type T. Great for the simple case of ints, but maybe not so great for custom types.

Comment: @Rhuidean here is the current error I am getting. I didn't include it initially as I have tried a bunch of ways to try and implement the operator and have just yielded to seeking help so I didn't know which attempt and corresponding error to present :S

Comment: Please copy-paste your source code, **do not retype it**. Your source code above has at least two typographical errors in it. This makes it heard for us to compile your program and fix it.

Comment: I thought this might happen, sorry. Copy pasting original code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate answer seems to be that you need to declare const-correct versions of your functions in the base template:

```
int getarrSize() const { return arrSize; }
T & getElement(int index) { return arr[index]; }
T const & getElement(int index) const { return arr[index]; }
```

A better answer might be that you can probably safe tons of work by using an existing standard container.